# Are mushy plums OK to use in cooking?

Tags: fruit

I have some plums that have started to go soft and squishy. Would they be OK in crumble / crisp / cobbler type recipes?

(I can't taste them before cooking because I am allergic to raw fruit).

Comment: At last, someone else allergic to raw fruit. We are a rare species. Any raw fruit and some nuts and seeds make my mouth itch like blazes.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall: It's called oral allergy syndrome / OAS and it's due to cross-reaction from pollens. When I was diagnosed with it about 10 years ago the internet hadn't heard of it and I knew nobody else with it. Now there's quite a bit of info out there (including lists of which fruits/veg/nuts are problematic depending on which pollens you are allergic to) and I know a handful of people who are fellow sufferers. Welcome to the club!

Comment: Interesting. I get hay fever too so pollen makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as they aren't spoiled they'll be fine for a crumble/crisp/cobbler. You'll want to have someone else taste them to make sure first. They may need less sugar and less or no precooking. If they are really, really mushy then you might want to add some firmer plums or other fruit to give some texture.

Comment: is there no way to tell if they are spoiled without tasting them?

Comment: (by the way, I am planning to mix them with some firmer plums and some nectarines, so I'm not worried about the texture - just whether they will spoil the taste)

Comment: Well, there's smell and appearance. If they smell rotten and are really gooey and brown then that's a good indication they are spoiled.

Comment: OK, they smell fine. They're a bit soft and mushy but not gooey. I'm going to risk it I think!

Comment: Sounds like they're just really ripe, now's the time to use them!

Comment: I agree with smell & appearance, but if you are really unsure after smelling them, you could throw them in a pan for a few minutes and taste them afterwards. Recipes which cook the fruit should work with pre-cooked fruit too.

Comment: @rumtscho is right, the only concern with that is if the fruit is already mushy it could lose all texture with pre-cooking. That won't stop you from cooking a small amount and tasting it.

Comment: I've now made it and am eating it as I type. Delicious and the mushy plums were not a problem at all :-)

Comment: Now I want a crumble, but it's 8am! Life is so unfair!

Comment: @GdD, is there a rule you're not allowed crumble at 8am? I'm screwed if so - cold crumble is the breakfast of champions! I've still got half of yesterday's left if you want to pop over :-)

Answer (score 1):

Having them mushy is fine, but check them for worms - they might be mushy for a reason, and plums get infested with really small, hard to see worms sometimes.